# How to retrieve data from Django fields?

Tags: python, django

I have a model

models.py

```
class EmployeeModel(models.Model):
    Employee_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    basic_salary = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    HRA = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    DA = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    TA = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    CCA = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    Medical = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)


    bonus = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    advance_pay = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0)
    PF = models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=12)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

All objects of my models.py

```
>>> employeeModel.objects.all()
<QuerySet [<employeeModel: Emp001>, <employeeModel: Emp003>, <employeeModel: Emp004>, <employeeModel: Emp006>, <employeeModel: Emp006>, <employeeModel: Emp0010>, <employeeModel: Emp0011>, <employeeModel: Emp0012>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp0013>, <employeeModel: Emp004>, <employeeModel: Emp0014>, <employeeModel: Emp0015>, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

For every instance of model 'EmployeeModel',I want to retrieve data from fields to calculate further in 'views.py' for Gross Salary! For example I want to get data of fields TA,DA,HRA individually so I can add them. But I don't know how to get data from Django fields. I'm new to Django.

Comment: employeeModel.objects.values_list('TA','DA','HRD') will display the data wanted

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP forgot to read the FineManual first.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers nope,have read finemanual, but still cant get proper way of getting results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Lemayzeur thanks sir for pin pointed answer, being newbie it hard to understand django manual in depth, as per your answer now i can finish my project. i implemented like this

```
query = employeeModel.objects.values_list('basic_salary', 'DA', 'TA', 'HRA', 'CCA', 'Medical', 'bonus', 'advance_pay',
                                      'PF','PT','leave','working_days').filter(employee_id=employee_id)[0]
    print(query)

    basic_salary = query[0]
    dearness_allowance = query[1]
    travel_allowance = query[2]
    house_rent_allowance = query[3]
    city_compensatory_allowance = query[4]
    medical_allowance = query[5]
    bonus = query[6]
    advance_pay = query[7]
    provident_fund = query[8]
    professional_tax = query[9]
    leave = query[10]
    working_days = query[11]
```

I know, its not dynamic, to retrieve data usually developers use API and ajax which i am going to learn next .